# Am I allowed to omit 'to be' after the verb "prove"

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to omit 'to be' after the verb 'prove'?

For example,

"This theory proved/proves **(to be)** almost impossible to disprove."

Comment: You happen to be completely right, but you should still give a source or explain what led you to this conclusion! It makes it easier for answers to elaborate on why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This theory proved/proves (to be) almost impossible to disprove."

"**This theory was very difficult to disprove**."

---

I would suggest there is nothing wrong with the grammar but your choice of words are incorrect.

In your sentence you needed to prove something to disprove it??? Quite how one does that I am not quite sure. Also I personally do not like negative sentences. Impossible is negative so is disprove. Hence my re-write. The use of "proves" could not be correct as you would have needed to disprove it before you could make the statement "almost impossible".

My final comment is that I would much prefer the statement **"The theory was eventually proven wrong".**. Which is what you are actually saying.

**almost** [ADVERB before verb]: You use almost to indicate that something is not completely the case but is nearly the case.

Comment: In my opinion it's the choice of _example_ that is incorrect (because it's clumsy to use _prove_ and _disprove_ in the same sentence). It would be fine to say "The weather forecast for the next day proved correct." This sense of _prove_ is not 'demonstrate the truth of', but 'turn out to be'. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prove

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Agreed.